# Getting custom calculated value in script field of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get the multiplication of two values in **script** field in elastic search as shown in the image. How to do this?

[image]

I am using below aggregation code

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "mention": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 20,
                "field": "username"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "mention_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "published_date": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "include": [
                                "klout"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": 1
                    }
                },
                "user_ranking": {
                    "max": {
                        "script": " 123 "
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```